# Обновление поля с текущей датой

Tags: c#, дата

Привет! У меня при запуске приложения C# в поле устанавливается текущая дата. Планируется, что приложение будет работать бесконечное число дней. Как дату обновлять в полночь без перезапуска приложения?

Comment: Привет:) @}->-По таймеру?

Comment: @Sergey, если по таймеру, то нужно будет интервал обновления установить, тогда придется ровно в полночь первый запуск провести...А ещё варианты есть?

Comment: Ничто не мешает установить таймер хоть через каждую секунду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"в поле" - в смысле, в члене класса? Сделайте его свойством:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public DateTime CurrentDate
  {
    get { return DateTime.Now.Date; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `System.Timers.Timer` и его событие `Elapsed`. Обработчик этого события выполняется в фоновом потоке и не будет блокировать интерфейс. `Interval` для таймера выставите секунду. Когда условие смены даты внутри обработчика выполнится, просто обновите поле, где хранится дата.

Если под полем подразумевается `textbox`, то тогда обновляйте его из фонового потока:

```
Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
          textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();  
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Вы не указали что за приложение (консоль,winforms, wpf, и т.д)

Если нужено обновление даты в 24 часа можно использовать что-то типа этого (достаточно подписаться на событие которое и оповестит о наступлении нового дня):

```
static class MidnightNotifier
{
    private static readonly Timer timer;

    static MidnightNotifier()
    {
        timer = new Timer(GetSleepTime());
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
        {
            OnDayChanged();
            timer.Interval = GetSleepTime();
        };
        timer.Start();

        SystemEvents.TimeChanged += OnSystemTimeChanged;
    }

    private static double GetSleepTime()
    {
        var midnightTonight = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
        var differenceInMilliseconds = (midnightTonight - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
        return differenceInMilliseconds;
    }

    private static void OnDayChanged()
    {
        var handler = DayChanged;
        if(handler != null)
            handler(null, null);
    }

    private static void OnSystemTimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Interval = GetSleepTime();
    }

    public static event EventHandler<EventArgs> DayChanged;
}
```

Можно и посекундно обновлять значение (пример из wpf):

```
public class Ticker : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Ticker()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000; // 1 second updates
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    public DateTime Now
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now; }
    }

    public DateTime Today
    {
        get { return DateTime.Today;}
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Now"));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Today"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```